# 60s(?) scifi story: astronaut comes back from space, slowly gets covered in rock, goes on a rampage

Tags: story-identification

I remember a story from when I was a kid, so it would be most likely early '60s.

An astronaut comes back from space but starts turning into a monster.  He is slowly being covered in rock and is having trouble breathing. The scientist try to cut the rock but can't get him out. Covered in rock/meteor, he goes on a rampage and starts killing people.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: _" the scientist try to cut the rock but can't get him out..."_ - just to check, were those several scientist**s** or a single one? (it's a tad bit unclear with the current wording)

Comment: Sounds a bit like "First Man into Space".  B&W from 1959.  A test pilot loses control of his ship in the upper atmosphere while passing through meteor dust.  He ejects.  The ship and pilot are covered by the dust which forms a hard rock coating.  Pilot looks like a rock monster and wheezes a lot because he can't breath.  He goes on a killing streak -- he needs to drink blood to live.  It has been a lot of years since I saw this movie, but I don't remember them trying to cut the rock off of the pilot, and I thought he was completely covered by the rock instantly after passing through the dust.

Comment: Thank you for your answer...  I do recall this, but perhaps it was a TV show of some sort?  I remember that the rock was slowly covering him and the scientists tried to stop it by cutting it open.   They could not.  Eventually it consumed him and as I recall he went mad.   Now mind you, this memory is very old.  Perhaps I am remembering something incorrectly or combining memories.   Thanks for your answer anyhow.